# stored procedure inside for loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

when i run the `call procedure` once it is working fine but if i put it inside for loop I'm getting error :

Here is my Code :

```
<?php 
    //mysql_query(mysql, "SET @increment = 10");
    for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
        $overall_dissat=mysql_query("call daily_sales('HO Bangalore','2013-07-01','2013-07-30')");
        if($overall_dissat===false) {
            echo mysql_errno().': '.mysql_error();
        }
        while($obj=mysql_fetch_array($overall_dissat)) {
           //print_r($obj);
           echo "<td>".$obj['sat']."</td>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Here's the error:

> 2014: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

[image]

Talking with the Call Procedure in mySql is working fine . but from php ....? How to achieve  it..

Comment: @cuewizchris I have gone through those already . But ther is no acceptable  answer from those .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure returns multiple result sets. A new query can only be issued on a connection after all pending results have been fetched. To process procedure call results you need to use mysqli_next_result() / mysqli_more_results(). See [example](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query).

Stop using mysql_* functions, they're outdated.

Comment: Downvoted for the "stop using mysql" comment. It isn't as easy as that for many developers who are programming for existing codebases where MySQL is the database of choices.

Comment: I did not formulate it properly so you misunderstood. I meant "Don't use PHP's old mysql_* functions" instead of "Don't use MySQL at all" (which of course would be a silly thing to recommend). My bad!